# Context missing from called test case

Tags: groovy, soapui

In SoapUI I’m running a test case from a groovy script with this code:

```
def contextMap = new StringToObjectMap(context)
def myTestCase_1 = myTestSuite.getTestCaseByName("TestcaseName")
myTestCase_1.run(contextMap, false)
```

In the called test case I set some context properties in a groovy script in this way: `context.setProperty(“ProperyName”,”Value”)`

After the called test case has finished the created property values are missing in the context of the groovy script that has called this test case.
How can I pass back property values to a test case that called another test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `context` if you want to share `properties` through different `testCases` in the same `testSuite` try to set the properties on the `testSuite` level which will be shared for all `testCases` in this `testSuite`. For example if you have a `testSuite` with two `testCases`: `testCase 1` and `testCase 2`, on a groovy script from `testCase 1` do:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "sharedVar", "someValue" )
```

Then to use this property from another groovy script in `testCase 2` use:

```
def shared = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("sharedVar")
log.info shared
```

You can also use this `testSuite` property saved in the `testCase 1` in the `testCase 2` for example in `testStep SOAP Request` using: `${#TestSuite#sharedVar}`

**EDIT BASED ON OP COMMENT:**

Since seems that the OP problem is how to get the properties from a `testCase` which is called from another `testCase` using groovy script; here is a possible work around, which consists in through the run result get the invoked `testCase` and then get his properties:

The first `testCase` which invokes the other `testCase` using groovy looks like:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap

def contextMap = new StringToObjectMap(context)
def testCase2 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("TestCase 2")
// get the result since is running sync
def result = testCase2.run(contextMap, false)
// from the result access the testCase and then the properties setted there
log.info result.getTestCase().getPropertyValue("varSettedOnTestCase2")
```

In the second `testCase` simply perform your logic and set the properties which will be get back from the first `testCase`:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("varSettedOnTestCase2","test")
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Defining the required properties at suite level make sense rather than defining at each test case level. However, it should not be like some value set by a test case and read changed value of the property in other test case does not seem to be good as there is dependency of test case comes in picture. I would think the test cases should be running independent. Just my view. Not sure if this is what the author of this post trying to do.

Comment: @Rao If you want to share a property through various `testCase` IMO the way is to put this property in the `testSuite`, probably this way you generate a dependency through `testCases` however in some cases could be necessary to reproduce the workflow that you want to test usign a property or properties throguh the whole `testSuite`. Summarize I think that this is a good or bad way to do so depending on the requirements... in this case I think that this is what OP is looking for. Thanks for comment `:)`.

Comment: I realize I forgot to mention an important thing. First I had set up the test cases with test suite properties. Running tests in parallel sometimes the following error will occur: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. I figured out that this error can occur when using suite properties in running test parallel. That is why I decided to change to context properties. At one point in the project it is needed to run another test case before continuing the current test case. But now it looks like I’m missing the updated context properties after the other test case is finished.

Comment: @Deduur If now I understand well your requirement you're looking for some way to call a `testCase` from a groovy script in another `testCase` and get the context used in the second `testCase` back to the first `testCase` isn't it?

Comment: @Deduur finally I updated my answers, I think that now you can get your properties back, hope this helps `:)`

Comment: Thanks. In this way it works. I was trying in that direction but didn’t exactly know how to access the parameters in the result and made the fault of using the context instead of the test case properties in test case 2.

Comment: @Deduur fantastic, nice to help you `:)`