# soapui context properties in script assertion

Tags: web-services, web, groovy, soapui

I've two test case A and B under one test suite

I am setting the context property in script assertion of one of the test step of B

```
def holder = new XmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContentAsXml )
context.setProperty("xmlHolder", holder)
```

I am getting the context property in script assertion of one of the test step of A

```
def Holder=context.getProperty("xmlHolder")
log.info(Holder)
```

but the value of "Holder" is printed `null`
I just want to set it in one TC and get it in the other one.

**EDIT**
Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159903/context-missing-from-called-test-case) , and I was trying to set property like this. I already had a Runner created in script assertion.

```
Runner.getTestCase().setPropertyValue("xmlHolder", holder)
```

But receiving a `null` error

I could do

```
Runner.getTestCase().setPropertyValue("xmlHolder", "A")
```

Just wondering , if TC properties can hold an Object compare to string. So, my original question remains as it is.

Comment: [user1207289](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1207289/user1207289), I believe that `Runner` variable is not available, instead `runner` is available. In my opinion, *soapUI* only holds `StringToStringMap`, so can't hold *objects* in test case / test suite / project level properties. You may try saving response string directly. Later, read that and convert it to `XmlHolder` object.

Comment: @Rao Thanks. Can `WsdlTestRunContext` be used to share context between TC. Got the information on net, but haven't tried it yet. Just thought you might have an idea about it.

Comment: In script assertion, have below line -`context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue('RESPONSE_FOR_LATER_USE', messageExchange.response)`

Comment: And use `${#TestSuite#RESPONSE_FOR_LATER_USE}` when needed in other locations within the same suite.

Comment: @Rao  Get the error `No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.attachments.WsdlSinglePartHttpResponse) values: [RESPONSE_FOR_LATER_USE, com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.attachments.WsdlSinglePartHttpResponse@9ffac9a] Possible solutions: setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getPropertyValue(java.lang.String)` on setting up the property.

Comment: How about `context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("RESPONSE_FOR_LATER_USE", messageExchange.response.responseContent)`?

Comment: @Rao  Thanks. Updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on above comments, got this working

setting property in script assertion of B

```
context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue('xmlHolder', messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
```

getting property in script assertion of B and converting it to `XmlHolder` object

```
def HolderContent=context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('xmlHolder')
def Holder = new XmlHolder ( HolderContent)
```